# Please give me the clarity on this

Tags: python, printing, output, func, alloca

```
num1=0
Stored_num=23

def input_num():
    num1=int(input('Enter the number again: '))

while num1!=stored_num:
    input_num()
else:
    print('Congrats ! The entered number mathched the stored number')
```

The code above is not accepting the else condition and not printing the message despite entering the stored value i.e. 23.

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have named the variable `Stored_num` and are using `stored_num` to compare. Python is a case sensitive language so these are not the same. Change one of them to the other and it should work fine.

Comment: @ mushahidq, Thank you, Sir, for your answer. I tried the same but the output was not as expected without the global scope variable in function. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have miss-typed the global variable and function scope variable.

num=0
Stored_num=23

def input_num():
num1=int(input('Enter the number again: '))

```
while num1!=stored_num:
    input_num()
else:
    print('Congrats ! The entered number mathched the stored number')
```

See, var Stored_num = 23 starts with capitals S, and inside stored_num start with small s.
Make both the variable name the same and it will work.

Comment: @ Rahul Maurya, Thank you, Sir, for your answer. I tried the same but the output was not as expected without the global scope variable in function. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes to your code:

```
num=0
Stored_num=23

def input_num():
    global num
    num=int(input('Enter the number again: '))

while num!=Stored_num:
    input_num()
else:
    print('Congrats ! The entered number mathched the stored number')
```

The outcome:

```
Enter the number again: 10
Enter the number again: 5
Enter the number again: 23
Congrats ! The entered number mathched the stored number

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Few notes:

1. Python does not share the global scope variables. If you need to modify a variable defined outside of a `def`, you will need to announce it by using `global`
2. Python is a case-sensitive language. (So `Stored_num` does not equal `stored_num`)

There was an error relating to `num1` that didn't exist. Just renamed it to `num`.

I think that was it. (:

Comment: `while does not require else. In fact, that's a wrong syntax.` Nope, it's valid syntax, just like `for-else`. Check this code snippet: https://repl.it/@gurukiran1/InnocentThirdKilobyte

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Will update the answer. Thank you for pointing that out! (:

Comment: @Rikki, Thank you very much, sir. Note 1 regarding global scope variables is really insightful from your detailed answer. I was unaware of it earlier. Thanks a lot, again.